# How to I send tweets to twitter from java

Tags: java, twitter

How to I send tweets to Twitter from java, looking for the simplest current solution please. As twitter always seems to be changing Im not even sure if this is possible and if there are any restrictions.

Comment: Did you even Google this? Literally searching your title, `How to I send tweets to twitter from java`, turned up LOTS of useful results. As a member for 5 years you should know questions like this are not acceptable.

Comment: Searching for 'Twitter Java API' on google might help more than asking such a broad question on here.

Comment: @tnw I was looking for a current valid solution rather than trawling through a load of out of date material

Comment: @PaulTaylor Thats how research is done. Whether if its digging through documentation or scouring websites to piece together bits of information. Even if the information is a bit out of date the method is likely still valid. Create a request, attach the body of the requests whoms format can be found in the well documented Twitter API docs and send it.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation

Comment: Ok fair nuff, seems twitter4j is the way to go

Comment: Blimey so many broken links on twitter4j and twitter sites, first problem is oauth with many conflicting explanations of what you need to do.

Comment: FWIW using twitter4j and folowing this blog post http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/java-twitter-client-with-twitter4j.html did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that twitter4j was the most comprehensive and uptodate api, to access anything on twitter you need to use oauth and I didnt find the twitter4j documentation on this very clear.

However this excellant blog post http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/java-twitter-client-with-twitter4j.html clearly explains how to use oauth and update your twiiter status (send a tweet). Read through it carefully and it tells you exactly what you need to do and is really quite simple.